# How to count the number of streaks in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

So I am trying to count how many times a streak of three heads or three tails appear on a list and print it. I had it working but it got deleted now it's not working correctly after typing it again I know I'm missing something.

```
numberOfStreaks = 0
flip = []
tStreak = 0
hStreak = 0
for experimentNumber in range(20):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        flip.append('H') # Add a living cell.
    else:
        flip.append('T')
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "H":
        hStreak += 1
        if hStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            hStreak = 0
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "T":
        tStreak += 1
        if tStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            tStreak = 0


print(flip)
print(numberOfStreaks)
```

output:

['T', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'H']

6

Comment: If you encounter a heads, you should set the tails streak to 0, and vice versa. Also, should streaks of 4 count as one or two streaks of 3?

Comment: streaks of 4 should count as 1

Comment: The code just counts the number of occurrences of T or H. It doesn't check at all if it's a sequence or not.

Comment: it does actually every time it see h it adds it to hStreak. once hStreak reaches 3 that means it appeared three times

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this to set tStreak to 0 when a 'H' appears and to set hStreak to 0 when a 'T' appears.

```
numberOfStreaks = 0
flip = []
tStreak = 0
hStreak = 0
for experimentNumber in range(20):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        flip.append('H') # Add a living cell.
    else:
        flip.append('T')
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "H":
        tStreak = 0
        hStreak += 1
        if hStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            hStreak = 0
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "T":
        hStreak = 0
        tStreak += 1
        if tStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            tStreak = 0

print(flip)
print(numberOfStreaks)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `count` method by converting the list to a string.

```
flip = []
for experimentNumber in range(20):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        flip.append('H') # Add a living cell.
    else:
        flip.append('T')
print(flip)
print(''.join(flip).count('HHH') + ''.join(flip).count('TTT'))
```

successfully!

Joinathan

Comment: I love this community. You can learn alot here and yall answer fast lol. That was the only thing stopping me from making one sooner

Answer (score 0):

Your comment suggests that a streak if 4 or more would count as one streak. I think it would make sense to rewrite the code like so account for that, since fixing your original code to cope with that would make it quite long:

```py
import random
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

flip = ['H' if random.randint(0, 1) else 'T' for _ in range(20)]

# get all the streaks of length >= 3 by grouping them
streaks = [face for face, group in groupby(flip) if len(list(group)) >= 3]

numberOfStreaks = len(streaks)
# add up streaks of each face
faceStreaks = dict(Counter(streaks))

print(flip)
print(numberOfStreaks)
print(faceStreaks)
```

Sample output:

```py
['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'T']
3
{'H': 2, 'T': 1}
```

This also gives the number of streaks each face had.

Answer (score 0):

Although the count solution is probably faster, I will try to explain how I would think if I was a beginner.

For solving the error I know that the problem is in the counting.
The code is counting too many because it counts non-consecutive coins as streak, for example "H,T,H,H".

But since I can't figure what's wrong, I will try to print each iteration:

```
numberOfStreaks = 0
flip = []
tStreak = 0
hStreak = 0
for experimentNumber in range(20):
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        flip.append('H') # Add a living cell.
    else:
        flip.append('T')
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "H":
        hStreak += 1
        if hStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            hStreak = 0
    if flip[experimentNumber] == "T":
        tStreak += 1
        if tStreak == 3:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            tStreak = 0
    print(flip)  # idented so prints each time
    print( hStreak, tStreak, numberOfStreaks) # same
```

First iterations result:

```
['H']
1 0 0
['H', 'T']
1 1 0
['H', 'T', 'H']
2 1 0
['H', 'T', 'H', 'T']
2 2 0
```

Now I see that it's counting each coin, not streaks! When a coin changes it should end the streak: one of the counters should always be 0.

One last thing: I like to keep code clean, simple and efficient. Everything should have a defined purpose.

For example: Why are we looking at the flips' list to know the element we just appended. This seems a little unintuitive. So my solution would be like this:

```
numberOfStreaks = 0
flip = []
H_streak = 0 #counters
T_streak = 0

for _ in range(20):
    
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0: # Flip is HEAD
        flip.append('H') # Add a HEAD
        
        H_streak += 1 # Change the counters
        T_streak = 0
    
    else:
        flip.append('T') #Add Tail 

        T_streak += 1 #Change counters
        H_streak = 0
    
    # If there is a streak we count it and reset the H/T counters
    if T_streak + H_streak == 3:
        numberOfStreaks += 1
        T_streak, H_streak = 0, 0

print(flip)
print(numberOfStreaks)
```

I hope that you find it useful and helps you learn! :)

P.S: keep in mind that this code might not do what you want. A 6 coin streak should be counted as 2 streaks or 4 streaks? If it's 4 you can try to change it ;)

Comment: Away from the computer but on that last part with this streak of 4 could you put a nested if-else statement at the end that checks if it was a t streak and if it is reset it to 1 Instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the list with itself using an offset of 1 and 2 to get tuples of 3 consecutive values.  Join these into strings (using map) and count the matches with TTT or HHH:

```
TF = ['T', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'H',
      'T', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'H']


count = sum(t in ('HHH','TTT') for t in map("".join,zip(TF,TF[1:],TF[2:])))

print(count) # 5
```

If you want separate counts for streaks of head and streaks of tails, compose the count in a large base to separate heads from tails and decompose it at the end using divmod:

```
count = sum( (t=='HHH')*len(TF) + (t=='TTT') 
             for t in map("".join,zip(TF,TF[1:],TF[2:])))
H3,T3 = divmod(count,len(TF))

print(H3,T3) # 0, 5
```